# input type checkbox not working inside bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Why is that checkbox inside the bootstrap modal not working?

I use this code to make it working but still have a problem

```
documentBody.on('click','.checkInp',null,function(e) { 
    var checkbox = $(this).find(":checkbox"),
    checked = checkbox.is(":checked"); 
    checkbox.prop("checked", !checked);

});

documentBody.on('click','.checkInp :checkbox',null,function(e) { 
  $(this).parent('span').trigger('click');

});
```

when i click it there is no check appears when its unchecked or it is not uncheck when its check? but if i click the span area the checkbox is marked as check or uncheck

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Snippet/BZRtx/5/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guess you try to overcome bootstrap modals `e.preventDefault()` in click events - this is why it never works. Also the two events seems to obsulete each other?

Try this instead :

```
$('.checkInp input:checkbox').on('click', function(e) {

    // prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree
    // eg the modal from cancelling the event
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    var checked = (e.currentTarget.checked) ? false : true;
    e.currentTarget.checked=(checked) ? false : checked.toString();
});
```

forked fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AurPX/

Answer (score 7):

The solution of davidkonrad is very nice. Although, it does not respect label-Tags. Here's a modified version:

```
jQuery(".modal input:checkbox,.modal label").on("click", function(e)
{
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var element = (e.currentTarget.htmlFor !== undefined) ? e.currentTarget.htmlFor : e.currentTarget;
    var checked = (element.checked) ? false : true;
    element.checked = (checked) ? false : checked.toString();
});
```

Comment: (Doesn't this run for all the labels, though? Not horrible, probably, but not precise.)

Comment: Imo, it should this way. It only catches labels inside .modal-elements.

Comment: Yes, it will, but there may be other labels present.

Answer (score -3):

I also faced this trouble, and It costed me one day to solve it by Jquery.

Unfortunately,there was no easy to be solved by JQuery, but had to switch to other way.

finally angularjs solved this.

try ng-checked.

```
<div class="modal fad"
....
<input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" ng-checked="checked">
</div>
```

js:just set it true like

```
$scope.checked = 'true';
```

Comment: Completely irrelevant to question; switching to a different front-end framework is certainly a solution, but it doesn't directly addressed the OP's question from over two years ago.