# How to make radio buttons work in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm trying to make normal radio buttons work in bootstrap. This is the code I have:

```
<input type="radio" name="something" value="a"> a
<input type="radio" name="something" value="b"> b
```

Why this doesn't work? I mean, when I select `a` for first, and then try to select `b`, it doesn't let it to be selected.

Comment: What you are describing is impossible. Probably some javascript on your page interferes?

Comment: So you want to disable b when a is selected? What happens if the user changes their mind?

Comment: I want radio buttons to work "normally". I have bootstrap's javascript referenced and when I move that loading from <script> tag, it works.

Comment: Your definition of "normally" doesn't match what you describe in the question.

Comment: I obviously mean that when I try to select "b" after selecting "a", I want "a" to be unselected. That's normal use case, don't you think?

Comment: Yes that is normal use, but your question reads differently, hence the confusion. Anyway like @dfsq says, there must be something else interfering on your page. Bootstrap will not mess with that level of functionality.

Comment: It does. I have this <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> just before the closing <body> and it doesn't work. When I comment that code, it works. You can try it yourself.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like it's because of ordering script tags. I had jquery script tag before bootstrap's and that's what was causing problem.

Comment: I just did try it and it doesn't affect my radio buttons. There must be something else on the page. In fact, here is an example: http://www.bootply.com/SQkhY4REhi

Comment: Last time I got such behavior it was a mismatch between the value of the for attribute of a label use for the radio button and the id of the radio button . This was yesterday. Hope it could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone will bump to same problem: I had radio buttons inside of bootstrap's modal. Here is what helped me:

[input type checkbox not working inside bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696321/input-type-checkbox-not-working-inside-bootstrap-modal)